# My Default Controller Can Not Find the Parent Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**My application is working totally fine in development environment. Once i uploaded it to my production server, i got the following error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ‘)’ in
>   /home/fjamal/public_html/*******/anyname/application/config/config.php
>   on line 27

**The errors refers to the following code:**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
 if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
  {
   include $file;
  }
  elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT))
  {
   include $file;
  }
 }
});
```

**If i change the above code to the older version as:**

```
function __autoload($class)
{
 if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
  {
   include $file;
  }
  elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT))
  {
   include $file;
  }
 }
}
```

**I get the following error:**

> Fatal error: Class ‘Frontend_Controller’ not found in
>   /home/fjamal/public_html/********/anyname/application/controllers/home.php
>   on line 4

**Explanation of the error:** my controller extends from Frontend_Controller which resides in Libraries folder. Frontend_Controller extends from MY_Controller which resides under core folder. For some reason, all these problems in the production environment, i don’t get it in my localhost. Hence, home is default controller.

***This error stops the application from running, i couldn’t figure it out at all. Any help will be appreciated.***

Comment: Either tell us which line is line 27 (and post lines 1-26), or just post the `config.php` file - it turns this question from "read and work out what you want" into "spot the fatal error", which is a much easier answer :P

Comment: You did change your base_URL in your production config file right? And your .htaccess file?

Comment: Which PHP-version is running on your production-environment?

Comment: Yes i changed base_url; Production server has PHP Version 5.2.17. My development environment has PHP 5.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your production-server is running with PHP <5.3

Your code uses a anonymous function, they have been introduced in PHP 5.3.0

Solution: create a named function and use it as callback.

Comment: Production server has PHP Version 5.2.17. My development environment has PHP 5.3.1. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I had to rename my file from Frontend_controller.php to Frontend_Controller.php. Hence, "function __autoload($class)" is compatible with 5.2.17